# Regular expression not progressing after first match

Tags: javascript, regex

The following code was my attempt to write a Regular Expression that would match both "cat" and "car" strings.

```js
(function (){
  
    console.log(/(ca(t|r))+?/.exec(["cat", "car", "catcoon"]));
  })()
```

The "ca" would be matched first, then the method would look for either a "t" or a "r". It is then wrapped with ()+? to allow for multiple matches.
However, the console shows `["cat", "cat", "t"]` indicating that is stuck after the first match.

Comment: You need to loop over the results. `exec` only returns one match per call. Read the documentation on it.

Comment: What you need of ah answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec` syntax is:

> ```
> regexObj.exec(str)
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> str The **string** against which to match the regular
>   expression.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

Your not passing in a string, your passing in an array. JavaScript will corece this into a string as best it can. Basically you need:

```
(function (){
   var arr = ["cat", "car", "catcoon"];
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     var str = arr[i];
     console.log(/(ca(t|r))+?/.exec(str));
   }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help!

```js
var result =["cat", "car", "catcoon", "cat", "car", "catcoon"].filter(x => /^ca[tr]$/.exec(x));

console.log(result)
```